# Синхронизировать input с многоуровневым объектом

Tags: javascript, объекты

Добрый день! Решил прописать имя инпуту, такое же как и путь к значению многоуровнего объекту. Чтобы проще было работать). Почему-то решил, что так можно). На примере будет понятнее:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);

var obj = {
price: {
 now:2,
 last:1,
}
};
var testForm;

function start(){
 var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
 testForm = document.forms.testForm;

  btn.addEventListener("click", setQuery);
 }

function setQuery(event){
for (let i=0; i<testForm.length; i++){
//получаю имя инпута: "price.now" и "price.last"
  var path = testForm[i].name;
  //пробую обратиться к объекту по полученному пути. Но это не сработало)
  obj[path] = testForm[i].value;
 }
 console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<form id="testForm">
<input type="text" name="price.now">
<input type="text" name="price.last">
</form>
<button type="button" id="btn">Внести изменения</button>
```

Может есть методы, которые бы позволили реализовать мою мысль?

П.С.: Хочется что-то подобно этого: вводим `elem.setAttribute("data-id","1")` имеем доступ через `elem.dataset.id`

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);

var obj = {
    price: {
      now: 2,
      last: 1,
    }
  },
  testForm;
  
function start() {
  var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  testForm = document.forms.testForm;
  btn.addEventListener("click", setQuery);
}

function setQuery(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < testForm.length; i++) {
    //получаю имя инпута: "price.now" и "price.last"
    var path = testForm[i].name.split(".");
    //пробую обратиться к объекту по полученному пути. Но это не сработало)
    obj[path[0]][path[1]] = testForm[i].value;
  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="text" name="price.now">
  <input type="text" name="price.last">
</form>
<button type="button" id="btn">Внести изменения</button>
```

Comment: ну да, это понятно. Я думал, может есть какой-то прямой, синтаксический способ или метод. Типа `elem.setAttribute("data-id","1")` имеем `elem.dataset.id`

Comment: @Дмытрык какой смысл в данном случае получать значение через data из input?

Comment: да это ж я просто пример привел. Есть метод `setAttribute`, после его использования имеем многоуровневый объект `elem.dataset.id`