# Установить объекту значение по строке типа "key.key2.key3"

Tags: javascript, input, объекты

Добрый день! Захотелось мне упростить работу с `input` при формировании многоуровнего объекта, для отправки на сервер. Мысль была простая, имена  `input` задавать такие, которые бы соответствовали ключам многоуровнего объекта. Например: `<input name="price.now">` `<input name="price.past">` `<input name="price.past.first">` и т.д. Задал соответствующий вопрос [Синхронизировать input с многоуровневым объектом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810535/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-input-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC). Но как выяснилось - стандартных методов для такой реализации нет. Вот попробовал написать свою, универсальную функцию для реализации задуманного. Вроде бы получилось.

См. ответ - укажите на недостатки моего кода, а также, предлагайте свои варианты реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, так будет немного проще:

```js
var startObject = {};
var inputName = "price.past.first";
var inputName2 = "price.past.second";
var inputName3 = "price.now";
var inputValue = 10;
var inputValue2 = 20;
var inputValue3 = 30;


setObject(startObject, inputName, inputValue);
setObject(startObject, inputName2, inputValue2);
setObject(startObject, inputName3, inputValue3);
console.log(startObject);

function setObject(startObject, string, value) {
  let path = string.split('.');
  let curObj = startObject;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!curObj[path[i]]) curObj[path[i]] = {};
    curObj = curObj[path[i]];
  }
  curObj[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var startObject= {};
var inputName = "price.past.first";
var inputName2 = "price.past.second";
var inputName3 = "price.now";
var inputValue = 10;
var inputValue2 = 20;
var inputValue3 = 30;


setObject(startObject,inputName, inputValue);
setObject(startObject,inputName2, inputValue2);
setObject(startObject,inputName3, inputValue3);
console.log(startObject);

//функция принимает объект, которому необходимо установить значение, 
//путь и само значение
function setObject(startObject, string,  value) {
  var arrString = string.split(".");
  startCicleFunc(arrString);

function startCicleFunc(arr){

(function step(object, i){
//проверка последний это ключ или нет
 if (i == arr.length-1){
  setValue(object, arr[i], value, function(objNext){
   step (objNext, i+1); 
  });
//условие выхода из рекурсии
 }else if (i == arr.length){
  return; 
 } else {

  setKey(object, arr[i], function(objNext){
   step (objNext, i+1); 
  });
 }

})(startObject, 0);

//создает вложенность объекту
 function setKey(obj, key, callback){
  if (key in obj){
   return callback(obj[key]);
  } else {
   obj[key] = {};
   return callback(obj[key]);
   }
 }
//присваивает значение ключу объекта
 function setValue(obj, key, value, callback){
  obj[key]= value ;
  return callback(obj);
 }
}

}
```

На базе предыдущей функции, сделал функцию получения значения по строке:

```js
var startObject= {
price:{
 past:{
  first:10,
  second:{
   one:40,
   two:50
  },
 },
 now:30,
},

};
var inputName = "price.past.first";
var inputName2 = "price.now";
var inputName3 = "price.past.second";
function getObjectValue(startObject, string) {
  var arrString = string.split(".");
  var c;
  startCicleFunc(arrString);

 function startCicleFunc(arr){

 (function step(object, i){
  if (i == arr.length-1){
   getValue(object, arr[i], function(resultValue){
    return c = resultValue; 
   });
  }else {
   getKey(object, arr[i], function(objNext,){
    step (objNext, i+1); 
   });
  }

 })(startObject, 0);
 function getKey(obj, key, callback){
  if (key in obj){
   return callback(obj[key]);

  } else {
   console.log("nen")
   return c;
   }
 }
 function getValue(obj, key, callback){
  return callback(obj[key]);
 }
}
return c;
}

console.log(getObjectValue(startObject, inputName));
console.log(getObjectValue(startObject, inputName2));
console.log(getObjectValue(startObject, inputName3));
```

Comment: Недостаток тут (равно как и в моем варианте), в том, что если задать `inputName3 = "price.past"`, то значения дли `inputName` и `inputName2` потеряются безвозвратно.

Comment: @Yaant, ну, в принципе, тоже самое произойдет, если присваивать значение объекту напрямую: `object.price.past = 10`, Десятка затрет собой любое, предыдущее,  значение ключа. Так что, я бы отнес это не к проблеме реализации, а уже к логике использования

Comment: Да, но тут ситуация чуть хуже в том плане, что если поменять порядок вызовов: `setObject(startObject,inputName3, inputValue3); setObject(startObject,inputName, inputValue);
setObject(startObject,inputName2, inputValue2);' то `inputName` и `inputName2` все равно пропадут.