# JS рекурсия - сделать код более качественным

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Написал функцию которая при получении строки(путь к конечному свойству объекта) из другой функции, разбивает его на массив и использует их в качестве свойств объекта. Объект имеет в качестве свойств другие объекты, глубина может быть сколько угодно. Функция вызывается рекурсивно чтобы добраться до конечного свойства и присваивает значение переданное в name.

Мне кажеться слишком громоздным функция. Есть ли по проще варианты написания?

```
const name = 'Jon';
const props = 'user.name'.split('.');
const recursiveObj = { user: { name: null } };
const recursive = (recursiveObj, index) => {        
 if (props[index] === undefined) return;
 if (
    index < (props.length-1) &&
    recursiveObj.hasOwnProperty(props[index]) &&
    typeof recursiveObj[props[index]] === "object" &&
    !Array.isArray(recursiveObj[props[index]])
 ) {
     recursive(recursiveObj[props[index]], ++index);
 } else {
   if (Array.isArray(recursiveObj[props[index]])) {
     recursiveObj[props[index]].push(name);
   } else {
     recursiveObj[props[index]] = name;
   }        
 }    
}
recursive(state, 0)
```

Comment: А обязательно рекурсией?)

Comment: Любой ваш вариант сойдет если выполнит ту же задачу и будет более легкий и доступный )))

Comment: может просто глянуть как это у `lodash`? https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L13126 и https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L3028

Comment: К сожелению я не работал с _lodash. напишите ваш вариант кода с _ lodash для примера

Comment: нее, вы можете просто взять код который они используют и все, посмотрите, там все просто и не так много.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810790/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-key-key2-key3

Comment: почему для массивов выделена отдельная ветка? Они как-то дополнительно обозначаются в пути?